# Git push fail over mounted windows dir

Tags: git

On Windows, pushing to a git repo which is mounted on a novell shared drive, I keep getting this:

```
remote: error: unable to create temporary file: File exists
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
```

Things I've tried

- checking I own and have write access to all the remote repo
- checking no `index.lock` files exist in the remote repo
- `git gc --aggressive` `git repack -a` `git prune-packed` on the remote repo
- checking I have enough space on the remote disk
- running `git push --verbose` (alas no more useful info)
- banging head repeatedly onto table... ;-)

Any more ideas?
(it's ok, I was lying about the table)

**UPDATE**

The same operations, pushing to a repo that's actually on my local hard disk, work just fine.  So this would appear to be a Novell issue.  Any suggestions on how to solve that would be appreciated, but if all else fails, at least I know I can use a different remote protocol.

Comment: Just an idea: Could it have something to do with case-sensitivity of the file systems? I once had problems with SVN when I checked out a repository from a NTFS to an ext3 file system. Can't quite recall and give a specifiy suggestion though.

Comment: Nice suggestion, just tried it, didn't work.  The initial push to the blank repo worked - it's the subsequent ones that don't.

Comment: when (for debugging purposes) you push to a repo on your local disk (C:) does it work? if yes, i suspect that some of git's assumptions about filesystems don't hold for novell shares. if no, it's more likely some general git/windows impedance mismatch.

Comment: Can you share the exact Git URI you're using? I'm a bit unsure about why there's that `remote:` prefix in the error messages while the operation is local. I might be barking at the wrong tree but anyway...

Comment: [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/_sMhQIcJIxI) might also be of interest even though it's about a different underlying driver.

Comment: @mnagel good call.  The same operations on my own disk work fine.  And fail remotely.  This is true both for a "url" of u:\my\remote\path and file://u:/my/remote/path

Comment: The exact "uri" (quotes as it's a windows path) is u:/blah/git (forward or backslashes seem to make no difference)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. What different remote protocol do you mean? Maybe you can post a workaround. Thanks

Comment: Yes.  I stopped using windows fileshares for this and now push over ssh for backup (already had a hosted linux account set up so this was the most straightforward answer for me)

Answer (score 1):

Had very similar problem with having a repo on a mounted Novell network drive. For me even `git add .` reported same error as yours. Installing the new version of Novell client completely solved the issue. I hope this helps someone who comes across this problem in the future.

p.s.
This is apparently a Novell-Windows-NTFS-MinGW issue only on a certain version of Novell.
Here are details, if you are interested:
http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Problem-pushing-to-a-Novell-share-td7248875.html